# Brand new external hard drive has 133MB used space?

Tags: external-hard-drive, disk-space

I just purchased a brand new WD Elements 1.5TB Hard drive.
I have deleted all the files that were on it, even the hidden ones, and done a "Quick Format" through windows explorer.

Yet, when I look at the disk properties, it tells me that there are 133MB of space in use. Now this is not a big deal, as the drive is HUGE, i'm just wondering where those 133MB are being used?

I've run CHKDSK on the drive and it tells me that there is 3093568 KB in 7 files.
Yet, ls -la only shows "$RECYCLE.BIN" and "System Volume Information" which appear to both be 0KB. Is it possible that these two files are taking up the 133MB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic disk overhead - file tables, NTFS information etc.

Comment: Ok, I thought it might be something like that, but I just didn't think it would show up as used space, I thought it would be subtracted from the total capacity of the drive altogether. Thanks.

Comment: It normally doesn't show up but I don't think it's much to worry about

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends met the same situation and there are two options for this problem.

You can check the disk with:

```
chkdsk /f /r /x [drive letter]
```

and see the results or you can run `diskmgmt.msc` and delete all partitions and create new partitions.

C: should be the primary partition and D: or E: should be logical partitions.

I think the second option will do all the maths.