# Newly formatted (NTFS) external hard drive already has 'Used space'. What determines the used space's amount? Is it correlated to the HD's capacity?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, external-hard-drive, ntfs, disk-space

I just bought a new external hard drive ([WD Elements - 1 TB](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=470)). In a PC with Windows 7, I formatted it by Right-clicking the drive > Format (Quick Format - NTFS) before using it and, and then checked out its Properties.

I noticed that it already has 118 MiB of its disk space already used, despite being newly formatted and no files transferred to it.

Questions:
**Is the disk space occupied by the disk overhead, metadata, etc. correlated to the total disk space capacity of an NTFS-formatted hard drive?

If yes, how is it computed?** (How much disk space will be 'used' by default on a brand new, newly formatted hard drive, given its disk space capacity and if it is formatted to use NTFS?)

Screenshot of the 1 TB drive's Properties after being formatted:
[image: Screenshot of Properties]

Related SU question: [Brand new external hard drive has 133MB used space?](https://superuser.com/q/207770/10259)

Comment: Where do you think the file system metadata is stored?

Comment: I always assumed it was spaced reserved by the operating system or the filesystem itself. See: [NTFS Master File Table](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-mft.htm). I'll pass this one on to a wiser user, since filesystems are not my forte.

Comment: @DanielBeck Hey! I'm the one asking the questions here. =) If you have an answer, please post it as an answer. Also, please note my question: *"Is the disk space occupied by the disk overhead, metadata, etc. correlated to the total disk space capacity of an NTFS-formatted hard drive? If yes, how is it computed? (How much disk space will be 'used' by default on a brand new, newly formatted hard drive, given its disk space capacity and if it is formatted to use NTFS?)"*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### tl;dr: This is space reserved for metadata storage.

This [article about NTFS technical side](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=ws.10%29) will give you some more details, but most of this space is taken by the **Master File Table**. (Some space is also used for the boot sectors, and so on.)

What explains a good part of the "bloated" metadata in NTFS compared to, say, FAT32 is the need to store **Access Control Lists** - although there are more things in there.

### How much space is used by the MFT?

There are 4 settings available when you format a hard disk in NTFS:

- Setting 1 reserves **approximately 12.5 % of the volume**. (Default)
- Setting 2 reserves approximately 25 %.
- Setting 3 reserves approximately 37.5 %.
- Setting 4 reserves approximately 50 %.

This is because the MFT size is proportional to your number of files. A standard (12.5 %) MFT size will be enough to provide metadata space for all your files if you fill the rest of your disk with 8 KB files.  Of course, since some files are going to be much bigger, this is an average.

If you store a  large number of smaller files to your disk, there won't be enough space to accommodate all their metadata in the reserved MFT space. This is not fatal, as a new MFT cluster will simply be created elsewhere. However, it will cause MFT data fragmentation, which is bad, as in, can cause severe performance degradation in some cases.

Comment: I see. Do you know how the metadata storage is computed? (How much disk space will be 'used' by default on a brand new, newly formatted hard drive, given its disk space capacity?)

Comment: Edited my answer to cover your more extensive question :) I also updated the link to a more technical article than Wikipedia.