# Why formatted flash memory has used space

Tags: memory, filesystems, ntfs, metadata, fat32

I format my flash memory and select its file system format as **FAT32** :

[image]

And then take a look at the flash memory drive properties :

[image]

As you see above, there is a 16KB used space.

---

I change windows options to show all the hidden files and system files:

[image]

And take a look at the contents of the flash memory. As you see it is empty :

[image]

To be ensure, I also list its contents with Command-line :

```
I:\>dir /A
 Volume in drive I is TRANSCEND
 Volume Serial Number is 7E4F-5898

 Directory of I:\

File Not Found

I:\>
```

As you see above, it's empty!

---

For your information :

`/A` in the command line, indicate to show all the file (hidden files, system files , ...)

```
I:\>dir /?
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
              Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
               L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
  /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
  /C          Display the thousand separator in file sizes.  This is the
              default.  Use /-C to disable display of separator.
  /D          Same as wide but files are list sorted by column.
  /L          Uses lowercase.
  /N          New long list format where filenames are on the far right.
  /O          List by files in sorted order.
  sortorder    N  By name (alphabetic)       S  By size (smallest first)
               E  By extension (alphabetic)  D  By date/time (oldest first)
               G  Group directories first    -  Prefix to reverse order
  /P          Pauses after each screenful of information.
  /Q          Display the owner of the file.
  /R          Display alternate data streams of the file.
  /S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
  /T          Controls which time field displayed or used for sorting
  timefield   C  Creation
              A  Last Access
              W  Last Written
  /W          Uses wide list format.
  /X          This displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file
              names.  The format is that of /N with the short name inserted
              before the long name. If no short name is present, blanks are
              displayed in its place.
  /4          Displays four-digit years

Switches may be preset in the DIRCMD environment variable.  Override
preset switches by prefixing any switch with - (hyphen)--for example, /-W.
```

---

This problem become more funny when I format the flash memory with **NTFS** as its file system format :

[image]

As you see below, it this case, I lose **125MB** of my flash memory space :

[image]

All the other steps that I did for **FAT32**, make the same output for **NTFS**

---

**Q1: What's the problem? where the origin of this occupied space?**

**Q2: Can I see those file[s] that use the space?**

---

Just to have more fun, I mount this flash (with formatted with **NTFS**) in Linux and take a look at it :

[image]

It is so weird! we have `87.2MB` used space! (**While it was 125MB in windows7**).

And let take a look at its contents via `ls -a` command:

[image]

Oh! Nothing again!

**Q3: Why used space is different for a single flash in two OS?**

---

Update: For `FAT32` format, both Windows and Linux [BackTrack in this case], there is no difference and in both we have `16KB`.

Appreciate your time and consideration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newly formatted (NTFS) external hard drive already has 'Used space'. What determines the used space's amount? Is it correlated to the HD's capacity?](http://superuser.com/questions/424622/newly-formatted-ntfs-external-hard-drive-already-has-used-space-what-determ)

Comment: FYI, the preallocated, used space is required by the file system, as it stores [file metadata](http://superuser.com/questions/792142/doesnt-metadata-occupy-any-size) (among other things). If you don't "lose" some space, how is the file system supposed to handle the actual files?

Comment: Is that not because of indexing. You need a list of address, to reach every sector at your HDD. If you don't have one, you would need to read a whole memory to find the things you like.

Comment: The bigger the list size, the smaller the size of cluster. So the probability is high, that you don't read more data, then you need.

Comment: This question is really like *"why does my metal bucket weigh 500g when it's empty"* - computers hide infrastructure from us, we can't easily see the equivalent of the bucket's metal body, hinge and handle.

Comment: No files means no file meta data, space should be unused. The calculation of free space already hides reserved sectors, file system metadata among other things so comparison to *metal bucket question* is BS.

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding FAT32

### TL;DR;

File size is calculated by counting free entries of the **File Allocation Table**, **FAT** can NOT be empty because of required root directory entry, therefore FAT filesystem always needs one cluster of space (= `Allocation unit size`)!

### Detailed answer

The FAT32 filesystem works in clusters, that is the `Allocation size unit` you selected. FAT32 by design needs **one cluster per file** + **one cluster for the root directory**.

The FAT32 file system contains following parts:

[image: FAT32 file system]

[From [Paul's 8051 Code Library: Understanding FAT32 Filesystems](https://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html)]

The clusters area is divided into clusters of same size, e.g. 4k, 8k, 16k and 32k. Each file including the root directory take one or more clusters:

1. The **Volume ID** specifies the cluster where the **root directory** STARTS, which is typically the third cluster, cluster 2 when counting from 0. ([`0x02C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#FAT32_Extended_BIOS_Parameter_Block))
2. The **root directoy** cluster contains **directory entries**, these are 32 bytes structures which give information about files AND directories, most importantly

   - name
   - kind of file (file or directory)
   - 1. cluster of the file/directoy
   - size of the file/directory.

   [image: Directory entry]

   [From [Paul's 8051 Code Library: Understanding FAT32 Filesystems](https://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html)]
3. To KNOW how many clusters we need to read for files and directory including the root directory we need to read of `FAT #1` or `FAT #2` which are **File Allocation Table**s:

   - Both FATs contain the same data for redundancy.
   - The FAT contains one entry for each data cluster.
   - Each entry is 32 bit long (hence FAT32),
   - A 32 bit FAT entry specifies either

     - the number of the next cluster for a file/directory,
     - that this is the last cluster (0xFFFFFFFF) of the file/directory,
     - that this cluster is empty (0x0).

```
|3: 0x5                           |4: 0x6                           |5: 0xFFFFFFF       |6: 0xFFFFFFF        |7: 0x          |8: 0x0 | ...
| 1. file start, next cluster 0x4 | 2. file start, next cluster 0x7 | 1. file ends here | 2. files ends here | Empty cluster | Empty | ...
```

So to read a file/directory, we

1. Read the starting sector and file size from the directory entry.
2. Find out subsequent sectors from FAT.
3. Read sectors in right order for *size* bytes.

**FOR AN EMPTY FAT FILESYSTEM** the FAT contains ONE entry at sector 2 for the root directory, specifying that this sector is the last one:

```
# for i in `seq 0 3`; do (fatcat -@ $i /dev/sda1 | grep FAT1); done
#     fatcat => FAT filesystem explore, extract, repair, and forensic tool
#         -@ <cluster> => display cluster info: offset, address, FAT entry
FAT1: 4294967295 (ffffffff) # sec 0
FAT1: 4294967295 (ffffffff) # sec 1
FAT1: 4294967295 (ffffffff) # sec 2, 1. and last sector for the root directory.
FAT1: 0 (00000000)          # sec 3, empty because there are no more files/directories.
```

For linux systems, commands like `df`, `stat` use the `statfs` system call, which calculates the used space of a FAT32 filesystem by reading all non-`0x0` FAT entries:

```
int fat_count_free_clusters(struct super_block *sb)
{
    ...

    free = 0;
    fatent_init(&fatent);
    fatent_set_entry(&fatent, FAT_START_ENT);
    fat_ra_init(sb, &fatent_ra, &fatent, sbi->max_cluster);
    while (fatent.entry < sbi->max_cluster) {
        /* readahead of fat blocks */
        fat_ent_reada(sb, &fatent_ra, &fatent);

        err = fat_ent_read_block(sb, &fatent);
        if (err)
            goto out;

        do {
            // WHEN FAT entry == 0x0 this entry is free space!
            if (ops->ent_get(&fatent) == FAT_ENT_FREE) 
                free++;
        } while (fat_ent_next(sbi, &fatent));
        cond_resched();
    }
    sbi->free_clusters = free;

    ...
}
```

[`fs/fat/fatent.c#L714` of linux kernel v5.13](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/fs/fat/fatent.c#L714)

Because your `Allocation unit size` (= cluster size) is 16kB, 16kB are already used for the one root directory FAT entry (3. entry, 0xFFFFFFFF).